# How to tell HSQLDB to allow identity definition for SERIAL?

Tags: hsqldb

I'm currently writing tests for a spring boot application which is using a postgreSQL database. During test I want to replace the database by some in-memory variant like H2 or HSQLDB. Sadly both do not behave the same as the postgreSQL database.

I have migrations that look like

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, ...)
```

This results in hsqldb telling me

```
SQL State  : 42525
Error Code : -5525
Message    : identity definition not allowed: FOO_ID
```

So apparently creating the matching sequence for the primary key is forbidden. Is there a way to tell hsqldb to accept this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set PostgreSQL compatibility mode in HSQLDB.

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE
```

Your table definition is then accepted and converted internally to the SQL Standard equivalent.

```
CREATE TABLE FOO(ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ..
```

Comment: I'm of course setting the pg mode in the connection string.

Comment: I checked the example I gave with HSQLDB version 2.4.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set PostgreSQL compatibility - for example in connection string for Spring application:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true
```